# How to fix on grailed error 500 internal server error for 'No such property. "" for class'

Tags: grails, groovy, virtual-machine

I'm just creating a website on grails and i'm just having trouble creating a search form

What I have is a system where I can search for patients from the data I have created.

I have setup the form, the search page, the results page and the controller file and it was working well until the results page spews out this error.

The domain class name is Patient so that should be set right.

It just seems like the controller file and the results page aren't connecting

The full error I'm receiving  is;

```
URI /patient/advResults
Class groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException
Message null
Caused by No such property: patients forclass:grails.orm.HibernateCriteriaBuilder
```

Here is the code for my results page;

```
Searched

for patients matching <em>${term}</em>.

Found <strong>${patients.size()}</strong> patients.

</p>



<ul>

<g:each var="patient" in="${patients}">

<li><g:link controller="Patient" action="show" 
id="${patient.id}">${patient.patientName}</g:link></li>

</g:each>
```

This is what i've written on the controller file;

```
def advResults() {
def patientProps = Patient.metaClass.properties*.name
def patients = Patient.withCriteria {
"${params.queryType}" {
params.each { field, value ->
 if (patientProps.grep(field) && value) {
ilike(field, value)
}
}
}
return [ patients : patients ]
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should shift the line

```
return [ patients : patients ]
```

1 line down. Now you are returning from inside the `withCriteria{}` closure...

Comment: Genius! thank you don't know why I didn't think that